# store long text - mysql wampserver

Tags: mysql, wampserver, longtext

i have a long text that I need to store inside  MySQL database. the text is:

> Prof. R.S. Marks has founded a NRF CREATE center 'Nanomaterials for
>   Energy and Water Management' in Singapore together with his colleagues
>   Prof. Ma Jan (NTU) and Prof. Shlomo Magdassi (HUJI). Other
>   participating colleagues are Prof. Ibrahim Abdulhalim, Drs. Levi
>   Gheber and Ariel Kushmaro (BGU); Profs. Ovadia Lev and Dani Cohen and
>   Profs. Hua Zhang, Xiaodong Chen, Huo Fengwei and Li Shuzhou (NTU).

I've used "longtext" and "longblob" but it didn't help. As I understand it is supposed to be able to hold up to 64k characters.

The reason for storing such a large text is that I am trying to build a small system for the users of my website so they can update "news" section without entering the code. something like small CMS...

Thanks

Comment: the text didn't enter the database.

Comment: Then the problem is not the length but something else. Did you escapce special characters like `'`?

Answer (score 1):

You need to escape special characters like `'` for instance. If you use PHP to insert data in database then use [REAL_ESCAPE_STRING](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)